# Db Connection strange behavior

Tags: c#, nhibernate, extension-methods

I'm gradually migrating an app from NH to Dapper. I'm using in many point the following strategy:

```
using( var uow=MyUowManager.BeginUoW() ) //obtain a session and open
{
     //do some NH sandard stuff
     ....
     //then use Dapper
     session.Connection.Query<Dto>(....).ToList(); // Dapper query
}//close session ( and connection )
```

this is quite common in my code and it usually always works, except than in a function "sometimes" the connection inside the `Query` extension method appear to be `Closed` while the debugger shows it as `Open` before entering the extension method. It is not a debugger ghost since Dapper throws an exception complaining for the connection state.
Program is multithread, but of course there is no session/connection share among threads, and always with the debugger I checked the thread being the same before and inside the extension method.
How could this happen ?

Comment: Have you tried using the connection's StateChange event to find when it closes unexpectedly? In particular, subscribe the event after opening, unsubscribe just before *intentionally* closing, and stick a breakpoint in the handler. When you hit the breakpoint in the handler, it closed unexpectedly. It *sounds* like NH shut it down for some reason.

Comment: @MarcGravell good suggestion, I wasn't aware of that event.

Comment: Is NH session or transaction committed before call to Dapper?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks to your suggestion, found it: nh was closing the connection, actually was the first time I use dapper after an NH call in the same uow. But there is a debugger flaw in order to me: connection status in the watcher appear to be "Open", this was the misleading part. It appear "Open" also after receiving the StatusChange from Open to Close, very strange.